# How do I get Konsole to show the correct information on the tab when using autossh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, kde, konsole

I'm a heavy **konsole** user, and having recently discovered **autossh**, I'm quite happy adding new tabs using

```
konsole --new-tab -e autossh user@hostname
```

Unfortunately, Konsole's tab text is not following the remote directory and host name like my tabs do when using regular **ssh**.

I'd like to correct this, because it doesn't tell me the hostname to which I am connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

konsole can be configured to set the title differently, you can control it by adjusting your currently used profile. put a '%w' where you want your the escape sequence of your shell to appear (read 'background answer' for how to do this). the problem with 'autossh' seems to be, that it does not indicate to konsole that you are now on a 'remote' host...

[image: konsole settings]

**background answer:**

the title of a konsole tab (or xterm) is controled by 'escape sequencing' coming from your shell. read '[How to change the title of an xterm](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html) and put those sequences into the shell configurations of every machine you ssh to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason konsole does not know we are in remote shells is because it only looks at 'ssh' commands as initializing remote shells.  If I use the format `ssh user@host` it shows the title properly.

But I am using a wrapper script called `sshr`. (format: `sshr host`).

`autossh` is also a wrapper.  So konsole only uses the remote command title when it sees ssh.

I have posted a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=287922) report for konsole after not finding any info on fixing it myself.